# Nested Microfrontend Angular

Tags: angular, nested, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I would like to know if it was possible in Angular to use microfrontends in a nested way. Let me explain, I have an application that uses within one component multiple times components from another application through microfrontends (module-federation). I wanted to ask if it was possible and how it could be done to nest microfrontends, i.e. I have an application that uses components of another one via microfrontend which in turn will use components of a third application via microfrontend. To do this I am currently utilizing components called containers within which I load components from other applications via loadRemoteModule. The problem arises when I load multiple microfrontends at the same time, has anyone encountered this problem or can tell me if it is really possible to use microfrontends in a nested manner as I explained above?